# Is there a way to share using name associated with a Google account?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'd like to find a way using Google Apps Script to share a document using the name. Because I am looking to share to people in my Organization, when I type in the share box they can come up using just their name.

I tried to find any way with the official api, but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way: You just send the autocomplete POST thingy that you can find by typing in the share box, and searching through the network tab for "autocomplete".

The tokens expire after a few minutes of no use, but if you continually run it, it is a viable option.